# to find Minimum and maximum element in an array using Divide and conquer error in function prototyping

Tags: c

I am trying to find minimum and maximum array in an array using divide and conquer method but I am getting this error it says that expected ';', ',' or ')' before '&' token. I tried to use divide and conquer technique to find maximum and minimum element by passing address to a function (reference of the variable)
[This is the error I am facing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdBOz.png)

here is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
void MinMaxDac(int arr[], int i, int j, int &min, int &min);
int main()
{
    int len, max = INT_MIN, min = INT_MAX;
    printf("Enter the length of the array = ");
    scanf("%d", &len);
    int arr[len];
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
    }
    MinMaxDac(arr, 0, len - 1, max, min);
    printf("Maximum element in the array = %d\n", max);
    printf("Minimum element in the array = %d\n", min);
    return 0;
}
void MinMaxDac(int arr[], int i, int j, int &max, int &min)
{
    //if array contains only one element
    if (i == j)
    {
        if (max < arr[i])
        {
            max = arr[i];
        }
        if (min > arr[i])
        {
            min = arr[i];
        }
        return;
    }
    //if array contains two elements
    if (j - i == 1)
    {
        if (arr[i] > arr[j])
        {
            if (max < arr[i])
            {
                max = arr[i];
            }
            if (min > arr[j])
            {
                min = arr[j];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (max < arr[j])
            {
                max = arr[j];
            }
            if (min > arr[i])
            {
                min = arr[i];
            }
        }
        return;
    }
    int mid = (i + j) / 2;
    //left sub-array
    MinMaxDac(arr, i, mid, max, min);
    //right sub-array
    MinMaxDac(arr, mid + 1, j, max, min);
}
```

Comment: in `int &min` replace `&` with `*` if you want to take/give a pointer - `int &min` is invalid syntax in C

Comment: can't I use reference instead of pointer?

Comment: C does not know "reference"

Comment: Either you program in C++ and can then use references. *Or* you program in C and can't have it. C and C++ are two *very* different languages. However, if you switch to C++ to be able to use references, then you can't have variable-length arrays.

Comment: got it, thanks for the input!

Comment: no problem @soma - hope you have a nice day :)

Answer (score 1):

You've used `&` where you should use `*` in your function declarations. `int &min` should be `int *min`.

You're also not dereferencing `min` and `max` when you work with them. `if (*min < arr[i])`.

In a declaration, `*` indicates a thing is a pointer. But in code `*` gets the value from a pointer ("dereferencing"), and `&` makes it into a pointer ("referencing").

- `int *min` says `min` points at an integer.
- `int *min = &num` takes a reference to the integer `num`.
- `*min < arr[i]` dereferences the pointer `min` to get its integer.

A good coding editor such as [Atom](https://atom.io/) or [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) will catch these mistakes for you.